# VLookup with multiple results adding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to lookup a value in another excel file that will have multiple results as rows. For example If the specific value is found in the column A of that row I want to add the number in column c to a total and then output that.

Book 1 VLookup from this sheet :

[image: LookupSheet]

Book 2 Vlookup destination:

[image: Destination]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

I would normally add what I have tried, but im completely stumped, the only real formula ive tried is a standard VLookup. The Watered down question is "Need to know: how many sales per unique sku?"

Comment: Use `SUMIF` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BigBen suggested in the comment, use `=SUMIF()` formula.

> in a pseudocode: *`=SUMIF(range_to_check, product_name, sales_amount_range)`*

So with the following data:

[image]

The formula in `E1` which you can drag to other cells in the column would look like:

`=SUMIF(A1:A6, D1, B1:B6)`